# View list of agents and recipients OBIEE

Tags: obiee, oracle-bi

I am trying to get a list of all of the agents setup in our OBIEE isntance.

I've found the agents in the table s_nq_job

However, I need the report that the agent is using, and a list of the recipients of that agent. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Analysis used in Agent is stored in S_NQ_JOB_PARAM.

Recipients in the Agent XML unless retrieved by a conditional analysis in which case you only get the list of recipients once the analysis is being run.

Comment: In the table s_nq_job_param, I see the path for the agent itself, but not the analysis the agent uses.

Where can I find the agent XML?

Answer (score 0):

The xml of the agent is in a file in the web catalog file system. And you only see the actual XML, if it's changed or deleted you won't have past code.